# Method from the library should not be called before declaring a particular variable

Tags: android, android-library, aar

I have created an android project and converted it into a AAR(Android Resource) File. I have imported the file in a new project.
So there is one class called `CollectSensorData` which is a singleton class.
the class is as shown below:

```
package com.example.android.sensordata.Main;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import com.example.android.sensordata.localdatabase.DatabaseHelper;
import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

public class CollectSensorData  {
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private static CollectSensorData instance;
    static boolean flag;
    private static Context mContext;
    public static int freqlocaldb, freqserver;
    public static SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static String URL;
    private CollectSensorData() {

    }

    public static CollectSensorData getInstance(Context context) {
        if(instance==null) {
            instance = new CollectSensorData();
        }

        mContext = context;
        return instance;

    }


    public void onStartTrip(String Job_id, String Cab_Number, String Driver_ID, long time) {
        String deviceModel = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + android.os.Build.MODEL;
        sharedpreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("trip", MODE_PRIVATE);
        flag = true;
        DatabaseHelper.tripinfo(Job_id, time, Cab_Number, Driver_ID, deviceModel);
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyService.class);
        mContext.startService(intent);
    }

    public void onEndTrip() {
        flag = false;
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyService.class);
        mContext.stopService(intent);
    }

    public void setFreqency(int FrequencyforLocalDB, int FrequencyforServer) {
        freqlocaldb = FrequencyforLocalDB;
        freqserver = FrequencyforServer;
    }
}
```

There is a string that is to be specified by the user. If the string is not specified the methods mentioned above - `onStartTrip`, `onEndTrip` and `setFrequency` should not work.

How do I ensure that the string is specified before any of the methods are called?

Comment: off-topic: please read this: https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html

Comment: To answer your question: `How do I ensure that the string is specified` you could do `if (userInput != null && userInput.length() > 0) { executeMethod(); }`

Comment: CollectSensorData.getInstance(this).onStartTrip(Job_Id,Cab_No,DriverId,time); This is the way the CollectSensorData is called from another application.